# Trying to acces nested key:value pairs in json but struggling to do this

Tags: python, json

Here is my json file:

```
[
    {
        "\ufeff_id": "6291ea573a34c0c800b7ebb5",
        "isV2": "FALSE",
        "isBeingMigratedToV2": "FALSE",
        "firstName": "Billy",
        "lastName": "Hargrove",
        "email": "billyhargrove@gmail.com",
        "country": "GB",
        "location": "GB",
        "referrerUserId": "607b38fb8673f55e32b",
        "groupName": "Billy Hargrove Wellbeing",
        "username": "billyhargrovewellbeing",
        "isTreeDonationsEnabled": "TRUE",
        "isSubscriptionless": "TRUE",
        "referralSource": "UNKNOWN",
        "userId": "6291ea571a1f277cc1d",
        "isEmailVerificationPending": "FALSE",
        "picture": "",
        "createdAt": "44709.39212",
        "carbonOffsets": "[{'_id': ObjectId('6291f6393a34c0c800b'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 10, 15, 21, 665000), 'projectId': 496, 'numberOfTonnes': 0.335, 'variant': 'donation'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6291f6393a34c0c800b'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 10, 15, 21, 665000), 'projectId': 497, 'numberOfTonnes': 0.165, 'variant': 'donation'}]",
        "trees": "[{'_id': ObjectId('6291f6391a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42693438, 'style': 'a', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 10, 15, 21, 657000), 'variant': 'donation', 'projectId': 113, 'name': 'Billy Hargrove', 'isEdenPriceMatched': False}]",
        "checklistItems": "[]",
        "apiKeys": "[]",
        "certificates": "[]",
        "badges": "[]",
        "__v": "0",
        "isNewsletterSubscribed": "TRUE",
        "blurb": "",
        "city": "City of Derby",
        "isBadgesHiddenFromProfile": "FALSE",
        "isPrivate": "FALSE",
        "link": "https://www.billywellbeing.com",
        "emailVerificationToken": "",
        "emailVerificationTokenCreatedAt": "",
        "subscription": "",
        "customerNumber": "",
        "billingCountry": "",
        "billingPostcode": "",
        "giftingUserType": "",
        "parentProfile": "",
        "isChildProfile": "",
        "chargebeeUser": "",
        "billingAddress1": "",
        "billingAddress2": "",
        "billingCity": "",
        "billingCompanyName": "",
        "billingEmail": "",
        "forestName": "",
        "pendingEmail": "",
        "isParentProfile": "",
        "referralImpactIncluded": "",
        "isUICancelled": "",
        "isDeleted": "",
        "isPayByInvoiceCustomer": "",
        "isAdmin": "",
        "isEdenPriceMatchEnabled": "",
        "isInvestor": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidFoundationEmails": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidTravelEmails": "",
        "isEmailDenyListed": "",
        "hasSeenPWABanner": "",
        "treeNumber": "",
        "hasNameAsCallout": "",
        "isTreeMode": "",
        "isCPWMonthsHidden": "",
        "isHiddenFromLeaderboard": "",
        "businessBlurb": "",
        "businessLink": "",
        "familyName": "",
        "locale": ""
    },
    {
        "\ufeff_id": "6291c45f3a34c0c800b7cfec",
        "isV2": "FALSE",
        "isBeingMigratedToV2": "FALSE",
        "firstName": "Eleven",
        "lastName": "Eleven",
        "email": "eleven@testingfinance.com.au",
        "country": "AU",
        "location": "AU",
        "referrerUserId": "",
        "groupName": "Testing Finance",
        "username": "testingfinance",
        "isTreeDonationsEnabled": "TRUE",
        "isSubscriptionless": "TRUE",
        "referralSource": "UNKNOWN",
        "userId": "6291c45f1a1f277cc1d",
        "isEmailVerificationPending": "TRUE",
        "picture": "2",
        "createdAt": "44709.27962",
        "carbonOffsets": "[]",
        "trees": "[]",
        "checklistItems": "[]",
        "apiKeys": "[]",
        "certificates": "[]",
        "badges": "[]",
        "__v": "0",
        "isNewsletterSubscribed": "",
        "blurb": "",
        "city": "",
        "isBadgesHiddenFromProfile": "",
        "isPrivate": "",
        "link": "",
        "emailVerificationToken": "7ad5a6e8ef8aee7684dfc953d8c5c7ac1239dddcdc637e20d985a421090f6e910ba30192e09b25e733f336698a7",
        "emailVerificationTokenCreatedAt": "44709.27961",
        "subscription": "",
        "customerNumber": "",
        "billingCountry": "",
        "billingPostcode": "",
        "giftingUserType": "",
        "parentProfile": "",
        "isChildProfile": "",
        "chargebeeUser": "",
        "billingAddress1": "",
        "billingAddress2": "",
        "billingCity": "",
        "billingCompanyName": "",
        "billingEmail": "",
        "forestName": "",
        "pendingEmail": "",
        "isParentProfile": "",
        "referralImpactIncluded": "",
        "isUICancelled": "",
        "isDeleted": "",
        "isPayByInvoiceCustomer": "",
        "isAdmin": "",
        "isEdenPriceMatchEnabled": "",
        "isInvestor": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidFoundationEmails": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidTravelEmails": "",
        "isEmailDenyListed": "",
        "hasSeenPWABanner": "",
        "treeNumber": "",
        "hasNameAsCallout": "",
        "isTreeMode": "",
        "isCPWMonthsHidden": "",
        "isHiddenFromLeaderboard": "",
        "businessBlurb": "",
        "businessLink": "",
        "familyName": "",
        "locale": ""
    },
    {
        "\ufeff_id": "6291b96d3a34c0c800b7ca81",
        "isV2": "FALSE",
        "isBeingMigratedToV2": "FALSE",
        "firstName": "Steve",
        "lastName": "Harrington",
        "email": "steve.harrington@googlemail.com",
        "country": "GB",
        "location": "GB",
        "referrerUserId": "",
        "groupName": "",
        "username": "steveharrington",
        "isTreeDonationsEnabled": "TRUE",
        "isSubscriptionless": "",
        "referralSource": "PRESS_ARTICLE",
        "userId": "6291b96d1a1f277cc1d",
        "isEmailVerificationPending": "TRUE",
        "picture": "0",
        "createdAt": "44709.24719",
        "carbonOffsets": "[{'_id': ObjectId('6291b96d3a34c0c800b'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 5, 55, 53), 'projectId': 4967, 'numberOfTonnes': 0.5025, 'variant': 'normal'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6291b96d3a34c0c800b'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 5, 55, 53), 'projectId': 4972, 'numberOfTonnes': 0.2475, 'variant': 'normal'}]",
        "trees": "[{'_id': ObjectId('6291b96d1a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42686004, 'style': 'b', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 5, 55, 57, 436000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 1799, 'name': 'Steve Harrington'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6291b96d1a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42686005, 'style': 'a', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 5, 55, 57, 436000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 3503, 'name': 'Steve Harrington'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6291b96d1a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42686006, 'style': 'b', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 5, 55, 57, 436000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 113, 'name': 'Steve Harrington'}",
        "checklistItems": "[]",
        "apiKeys": "[]",
        "certificates": "[]",
        "badges": "[]",
        "__v": "0",
        "isNewsletterSubscribed": "",
        "blurb": "",
        "city": "",
        "isBadgesHiddenFromProfile": "",
        "isPrivate": "",
        "link": "",
        "emailVerificationToken": "6d4269271d041ad93b3ea449de8160a1d28c37f55268e6dac24a76d07bf63f296bcd8c77ef5afba83a2c09dc054",
        "emailVerificationTokenCreatedAt": "44709.24719",
        "subscription": "{'_id': ObjectId('6291b96d3a34c0c800b'), 'chargebeeId': 'AzydTzT76bU3', 'currencyCode': 'GBP', 'customerId': 'AzydTzT76bU3', 'nextBillingAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 28, 5, 55, 53), 'numberOfMonthsPaid': 1, 'planId': 'booster-v3-gbp', 'startedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 5, 55, 53), 'addons': [], 'campaign': None, 'maskedCardNumber': '************1234'}",
        "customerNumber": "477",
        "billingCountry": "GB",
        "billingPostcode": "CF11987",
        "giftingUserType": "",
        "parentProfile": "",
        "isChildProfile": "",
        "chargebeeUser": "",
        "billingAddress1": "",
        "billingAddress2": "",
        "billingCity": "",
        "billingCompanyName": "",
        "billingEmail": "",
        "forestName": "",
        "pendingEmail": "",
        "isParentProfile": "",
        "referralImpactIncluded": "",
        "isUICancelled": "",
        "isDeleted": "",
        "isPayByInvoiceCustomer": "",
        "isAdmin": "",
        "isEdenPriceMatchEnabled": "",
        "isInvestor": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidFoundationEmails": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidTravelEmails": "",
        "isEmailDenyListed": "",
        "hasSeenPWABanner": "",
        "treeNumber": "",
        "hasNameAsCallout": "",
        "isTreeMode": "",
        "isCPWMonthsHidden": "",
        "isHiddenFromLeaderboard": "",
        "businessBlurb": "",
        "businessLink": "",
        "familyName": "",
        "locale": ""
    },
    {
        "\ufeff_id": "6291b4113a34c0c800b7c894",
        "isV2": "FALSE",
        "isBeingMigratedToV2": "FALSE",
        "firstName": "Will",
        "lastName": "Byers",
        "email": "will@theupsidedown.com",
        "country": "AU",
        "location": "AU",
        "referrerUserId": "",
        "groupName": "Upside Down",
        "username": "upsidedown",
        "isTreeDonationsEnabled": "TRUE",
        "isSubscriptionless": "TRUE",
        "referralSource": "UNKNOWN",
        "userId": "6291b4111a1f277cc1d",
        "isEmailVerificationPending": "TRUE",
        "picture": "3",
        "createdAt": "44709.23131",
        "carbonOffsets": "[]",
        "trees": "[]",
        "checklistItems": "[]",
        "apiKeys": "[]",
        "certificates": "[]",
        "badges": "[]",
        "__v": "0",
        "isNewsletterSubscribed": "",
        "blurb": "",
        "city": "",
        "isBadgesHiddenFromProfile": "",
        "isPrivate": "",
        "link": "",
        "emailVerificationToken": "8912d938d611503d67feb995e2d8c1c1a4cb942886d8d1e63e7a8b5cc55624325a8af623151c59dccf6fddbafb6",
        "emailVerificationTokenCreatedAt": "44709.2313",
        "subscription": "",
        "customerNumber": "",
        "billingCountry": "",
        "billingPostcode": "",
        "giftingUserType": "",
        "parentProfile": "",
        "isChildProfile": "",
        "chargebeeUser": "",
        "billingAddress1": "",
        "billingAddress2": "",
        "billingCity": "",
        "billingCompanyName": "",
        "billingEmail": "",
        "forestName": "",
        "pendingEmail": "",
        "isParentProfile": "",
        "referralImpactIncluded": "",
        "isUICancelled": "",
        "isDeleted": "",
        "isPayByInvoiceCustomer": "",
        "isAdmin": "",
        "isEdenPriceMatchEnabled": "",
        "isInvestor": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidFoundationEmails": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidTravelEmails": "",
        "isEmailDenyListed": "",
        "hasSeenPWABanner": "",
        "treeNumber": "",
        "hasNameAsCallout": "",
        "isTreeMode": "",
        "isCPWMonthsHidden": "",
        "isHiddenFromLeaderboard": "",
        "businessBlurb": "",
        "businessLink": "",
        "familyName": "",
        "locale": ""
    },
    {
        "\ufeff_id": "62914ab53a34c0c800b7a599",
        "isV2": "FALSE",
        "isBeingMigratedToV2": "FALSE",
        "firstName": "Max",
        "lastName": "Mayfield",
        "email": "maxmay@gmail.com",
        "country": "GB",
        "location": "GB",
        "referrerUserId": "",
        "groupName": "Max Mayfield",
        "username": "maxmay",
        "isTreeDonationsEnabled": "TRUE",
        "isSubscriptionless": "TRUE",
        "referralSource": "UNKNOWN",
        "userId": "62914ab51a1f277cc1d",
        "isEmailVerificationPending": "FALSE",
        "picture": "",
        "createdAt": "44708.91913",
        "carbonOffsets": "[]",
        "trees": "[]",
        "checklistItems": "[]",
        "apiKeys": "[{'_id': ObjectId('6291565d3a34c0c800b'), 'key': 'de79290d-a964-f716-6017-13a2dc1', 'description': 'Max Mayfield', 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 22, 53, 17, 422000)}]",
        "certificates": "[]",
        "badges": "[]",
        "__v": "0",
        "isNewsletterSubscribed": "TRUE",
        "blurb": "",
        "city": "Telford",
        "isBadgesHiddenFromProfile": "FALSE",
        "isPrivate": "FALSE",
        "link": "https://maxmay.co.uk",
        "emailVerificationToken": "",
        "emailVerificationTokenCreatedAt": "",
        "subscription": "",
        "customerNumber": "",
        "billingCountry": "",
        "billingPostcode": "",
        "giftingUserType": "",
        "parentProfile": "",
        "isChildProfile": "",
        "chargebeeUser": "",
        "billingAddress1": "",
        "billingAddress2": "",
        "billingCity": "",
        "billingCompanyName": "",
        "billingEmail": "",
        "forestName": "",
        "pendingEmail": "",
        "isParentProfile": "",
        "referralImpactIncluded": "",
        "isUICancelled": "",
        "isDeleted": "",
        "isPayByInvoiceCustomer": "",
        "isAdmin": "",
        "isEdenPriceMatchEnabled": "",
        "isInvestor": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidFoundationEmails": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidTravelEmails": "",
        "isEmailDenyListed": "",
        "hasSeenPWABanner": "",
        "treeNumber": "",
        "hasNameAsCallout": "",
        "isTreeMode": "",
        "isCPWMonthsHidden": "",
        "isHiddenFromLeaderboard": "",
        "businessBlurb": "",
        "businessLink": "",
        "familyName": "",
        "locale": ""
    },
    {
        "\ufeff_id": "62913f213a34c0c800b79cec",
        "isV2": "FALSE",
        "isBeingMigratedToV2": "FALSE",
        "firstName": "Mike",
        "lastName": "Wheeler",
        "email": "mikewheeler@gmail.com",
        "country": "GB",
        "location": "GB",
        "referrerUserId": "",
        "groupName": "Mike's Streetfood",
        "username": "mikesstreetfood",
        "isTreeDonationsEnabled": "TRUE",
        "isSubscriptionless": "TRUE",
        "referralSource": "UNKNOWN",
        "userId": "62913f211a1f277cc1d",
        "isEmailVerificationPending": "TRUE",
        "picture": "3",
        "createdAt": "44708.88483",
        "carbonOffsets": "[]",
        "trees": "[]",
        "checklistItems": "[]",
        "apiKeys": "[]",
        "certificates": "[]",
        "badges": "[]",
        "__v": "0",
        "isNewsletterSubscribed": "",
        "blurb": "",
        "city": "",
        "isBadgesHiddenFromProfile": "",
        "isPrivate": "",
        "link": "",
        "emailVerificationToken": "bda4d91347c0451494fb654b1ca89ea3f1a740ef9c18754b05790ec2b26bcea94fceda1762be00c9fbdc9c4f77a",
        "emailVerificationTokenCreatedAt": "44708.88483",
        "subscription": "",
        "customerNumber": "",
        "billingCountry": "",
        "billingPostcode": "",
        "giftingUserType": "",
        "parentProfile": "",
        "isChildProfile": "",
        "chargebeeUser": "",
        "billingAddress1": "",
        "billingAddress2": "",
        "billingCity": "",
        "billingCompanyName": "",
        "billingEmail": "",
        "forestName": "",
        "pendingEmail": "",
        "isParentProfile": "",
        "referralImpactIncluded": "",
        "isUICancelled": "",
        "isDeleted": "",
        "isPayByInvoiceCustomer": "",
        "isAdmin": "",
        "isEdenPriceMatchEnabled": "",
        "isInvestor": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidFoundationEmails": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidTravelEmails": "",
        "isEmailDenyListed": "",
        "hasSeenPWABanner": "",
        "treeNumber": "",
        "hasNameAsCallout": "",
        "isTreeMode": "",
        "isCPWMonthsHidden": "",
        "isHiddenFromLeaderboard": "",
        "businessBlurb": "",
        "businessLink": "",
        "familyName": "",
        "locale": ""
    },
    {
        "\ufeff_id": "629113253a34c0c800b778e9",
        "isV2": "FALSE",
        "isBeingMigratedToV2": "FALSE",
        "firstName": "Dustin ",
        "lastName": "Henderson",
        "email": "dusty@gmail.com",
        "country": "US",
        "location": "US",
        "referrerUserId": "",
        "groupName": "",
        "username": "dustyh",
        "isTreeDonationsEnabled": "TRUE",
        "isSubscriptionless": "",
        "referralSource": "SOCIAL_MEDIA",
        "userId": "629113251a1f277cc1d",
        "isEmailVerificationPending": "TRUE",
        "picture": "2",
        "createdAt": "44708.7545",
        "carbonOffsets": "[{'_id': ObjectId('629113253a34c0c800b'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 18, 6, 25), 'projectId': 4967, 'numberOfTonnes': 1.2261, 'variant': 'normal'}, {'_id': ObjectId('629113253a34c0c800b'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 18, 6, 25), 'projectId': 4972, 'numberOfTonnes': 0.6039, 'variant': 'normal'}]",
        "trees": "[{'_id': ObjectId('629113251a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42679080, 'style': 'b', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 18, 6, 29, 78000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 3503, 'name': 'Dustin Henderson'}, {'_id': ObjectId('629113251a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42679081, 'style': 'a', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 18, 6, 29, 78000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 113, 'name': 'Dustin Henderson'}, {'_id': ObjectId('629113251a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42679082, 'style': 'a', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 18, 6, 29, 78000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 113, 'name': 'Dustin Henderson'}, {'_id': ObjectId('629113251a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42679083, 'style': 'a', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 18, 6, 29, 78000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 113, 'name': 'Dustin Henderson'}, {'_id': ObjectId('629113251a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42679084, 'style': 'b', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 18, 6, 29, 78000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 1799, 'name': 'Dustin Henderson'}, {'_id': ObjectId('629113251a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42679085, 'style': 'b', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 18, 6, 29, 78000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 1799, 'name': 'Dustin Henderson'}, {'_id': ObjectId('629113251a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42679086, 'style': 'a', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 18, 6, 29, 78000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 3503, 'name': 'Dustin Henderson'}]",
        "checklistItems": "[]",
        "apiKeys": "[]",
        "certificates": "[]",
        "badges": "[]",
        "__v": "0",
        "isNewsletterSubscribed": "",
        "blurb": "",
        "city": "",
        "isBadgesHiddenFromProfile": "",
        "isPrivate": "",
        "link": "",
        "emailVerificationToken": "9fb77b335edd9afcfacdccecef5010d9af133d7f607609b582c5f45ee86ff0e65c2884955d924d53ffba45b6f34",
        "emailVerificationTokenCreatedAt": "44708.7545",
        "subscription": "{'_id': ObjectId('629113253a34c0c800b'), 'chargebeeId': 'AzZddVT73is6', 'currencyCode': 'USD', 'customerId': 'AzZddVT73is6', 'nextBillingAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 27, 18, 6, 25), 'numberOfMonthsPaid': 1, 'planId': 'mega-v3-usd', 'startedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 18, 6, 25), 'addons': [], 'campaign': None, 'maskedCardNumber': '***********4321'}",
        "customerNumber": "477",
        "billingCountry": "US",
        "billingPostcode": "90099",
        "giftingUserType": "",
        "parentProfile": "",
        "isChildProfile": "",
        "chargebeeUser": "",
        "billingAddress1": "",
        "billingAddress2": "",
        "billingCity": "",
        "billingCompanyName": "",
        "billingEmail": "",
        "forestName": "",
        "pendingEmail": "",
        "isParentProfile": "",
        "referralImpactIncluded": "",
        "isUICancelled": "",
        "isDeleted": "",
        "isPayByInvoiceCustomer": "",
        "isAdmin": "",
        "isEdenPriceMatchEnabled": "",
        "isInvestor": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidFoundationEmails": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidTravelEmails": "",
        "isEmailDenyListed": "",
        "hasSeenPWABanner": "",
        "treeNumber": "",
        "hasNameAsCallout": "",
        "isTreeMode": "",
        "isCPWMonthsHidden": "",
        "isHiddenFromLeaderboard": "",
        "businessBlurb": "",
        "businessLink": "",
        "familyName": "",
        "locale": ""
    },
    {
        "\ufeff_id": "629109363a34c0c800b770de",
        "isV2": "FALSE",
        "isBeingMigratedToV2": "FALSE",
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Wheeler",
        "email": "stranger@things.com",
        "country": "",
        "location": "AU",
        "referrerUserId": "",
        "groupName": "",
        "username": "nancywheeler",
        "isTreeDonationsEnabled": "TRUE",
        "isSubscriptionless": "",
        "referralSource": "UNKNOWN",
        "userId": "629109361a1f277cc1d",
        "isEmailVerificationPending": "FALSE",
        "picture": "3",
        "createdAt": "44708.72508",
        "carbonOffsets": "[{'_id': ObjectId('629109363a34c0c800b'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 17, 24, 6), 'projectId': 4967, 'numberOfTonnes': 0.3069, 'variant': 'gift'}, {'_id': ObjectId('629109363a34c0c800b'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 17, 24, 6), 'projectId': 4972, 'numberOfTonnes': 0.1511, 'variant': 'gift'}]",
        "trees": "[{'_id': ObjectId('629109361a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42678389, 'style': 'b', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 17, 24, 6, 640000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 1799, 'name': 'Nancy Wheeler'}, {'_id': ObjectId('629109361a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42678390, 'style': 'b', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 17, 24, 6, 640000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 113, 'name': 'Nancy Wheeler'}]",
        "checklistItems": "[]",
        "apiKeys": "[]",
        "certificates": "[]",
        "badges": "[]",
        "__v": "0",
        "isNewsletterSubscribed": "TRUE",
        "blurb": "",
        "city": "",
        "isBadgesHiddenFromProfile": "",
        "isPrivate": "",
        "link": "",
        "emailVerificationToken": "",
        "emailVerificationTokenCreatedAt": "",
        "subscription": "{'_id': ObjectId('629109363a34c0c800b'), 'chargebeeId': '16CLVQT73YDa', 'currencyCode': 'AUD', 'customerId': '16CLVQT73YDa', 'nextBillingAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 27, 17, 24, 6), 'numberOfMonthsPaid': 1, 'planId': 'personal-v3-aud', 'startedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 17, 24, 6), 'addons': [], 'campaign': None}",
        "customerNumber": "477",
        "billingCountry": "",
        "billingPostcode": "",
        "giftingUserType": "CLIMATE",
        "parentProfile": "",
        "isChildProfile": "",
        "chargebeeUser": "",
        "billingAddress1": "",
        "billingAddress2": "",
        "billingCity": "",
        "billingCompanyName": "",
        "billingEmail": "",
        "forestName": "",
        "pendingEmail": "",
        "isParentProfile": "",
        "referralImpactIncluded": "",
        "isUICancelled": "",
        "isDeleted": "",
        "isPayByInvoiceCustomer": "",
        "isAdmin": "",
        "isEdenPriceMatchEnabled": "",
        "isInvestor": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidFoundationEmails": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidTravelEmails": "",
        "isEmailDenyListed": "",
        "hasSeenPWABanner": "",
        "treeNumber": "",
        "hasNameAsCallout": "",
        "isTreeMode": "",
        "isCPWMonthsHidden": "",
        "isHiddenFromLeaderboard": "",
        "businessBlurb": "",
        "businessLink": "",
        "familyName": "",
        "locale": ""
    },
    {
        "\ufeff_id": "6290fc763a34c0c800b76558",
        "isV2": "FALSE",
        "isBeingMigratedToV2": "FALSE",
        "firstName": "Eddie",
        "lastName": "Munson",
        "email": "eddie@boatshedbeers.dk",
        "country": "DK",
        "location": "DK",
        "referrerUserId": "",
        "groupName": "Boatshed Beers",
        "username": "boatshedbeers",
        "isTreeDonationsEnabled": "TRUE",
        "isSubscriptionless": "",
        "referralSource": "FRIEND",
        "userId": "6290fc761a1f277cc1d",
        "isEmailVerificationPending": "FALSE",
        "picture": "",
        "createdAt": "44708.6873",
        "carbonOffsets": "[{'_id': ObjectId('6290fc763a34c0c800b'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 16, 29, 36), 'projectId': 4967, 'numberOfTonnes': 0.7571, 'variant': 'normal'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6290fc763a34c0c800b'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 16, 29, 36), 'projectId': 4972, 'numberOfTonnes': 0.3729, 'variant': 'normal'}]",
        "trees": "[{'_id': ObjectId('6290fc761a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42677378, 'style': 'a', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 16, 29, 42, 433000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 1799, 'name': 'Cerveza Collection'}, {'_id': ObjectId('6290fc761a1f277cc1d'), 'treeNumber': 42677379, 'style': 'a', 'value': 1, 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 16, 29, 42, 433000), 'variant': 'normal', 'projectId': 3503, 'name': 'Boatshed Beers'}]",
        "checklistItems": "[]",
        "apiKeys": "[]",
        "certificates": "[]",
        "badges": "[]",
        "__v": "0",
        "isNewsletterSubscribed": "TRUE",
        "blurb": "",
        "city": "",
        "isBadgesHiddenFromProfile": "FALSE",
        "isPrivate": "FALSE",
        "link": "http://boatshedbeers.com",
        "emailVerificationToken": "",
        "emailVerificationTokenCreatedAt": "",
        "subscription": "{'_id': ObjectId('6290fc763a34c0c800b'), 'chargebeeId': '16A01PT73KUs', 'currencyCode': 'EUR', 'customerId': '16A01PT73KUs', 'nextBillingAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 27, 16, 29, 36), 'numberOfMonthsPaid': 1, 'planId': 'business-v3-eur', 'startedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 16, 29, 36), 'addons': [{'_id': ObjectId('6290fc763a34c0c800b'), 'id': 'tier-1-v3-eur', 'quantity': 3}], 'campaign': None, 'maskedCardNumber': '************9953'}",
        "customerNumber": "50",
        "billingCountry": "DK",
        "billingPostcode": "261635",
        "giftingUserType": "",
        "parentProfile": "",
        "isChildProfile": "",
        "chargebeeUser": "",
        "billingAddress1": "",
        "billingAddress2": "",
        "billingCity": "",
        "billingCompanyName": "",
        "billingEmail": "",
        "forestName": "",
        "pendingEmail": "",
        "isParentProfile": "",
        "referralImpactIncluded": "",
        "isUICancelled": "",
        "isDeleted": "",
        "isPayByInvoiceCustomer": "",
        "isAdmin": "",
        "isEdenPriceMatchEnabled": "",
        "isInvestor": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidFoundationEmails": "",
        "isSubscribedToIntrepidTravelEmails": "",
        "isEmailDenyListed": "",
        "hasSeenPWABanner": "",
        "treeNumber": "",
        "hasNameAsCallout": "",
        "isTreeMode": "",
        "isCPWMonthsHidden": "",
        "isHiddenFromLeaderboard": "",
        "businessBlurb": "",
        "businessLink": "",
        "familyName": "",
        "locale": ""
    }
]
```

I am trying to access the key:value pairs withing the "subscription" field. I realise that for some this is empty, but for those that are not, any thoughts on how to go about it?
I have tried the following:

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
import objectpath


def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []

    # read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        # load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

        # convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader:
            # add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)

    # convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)


csvFilePath = r'users.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'users.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)

# flatten json file to unwrap nested array
file_name = 'users.json'

with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    my_data = json.load(f)

    print(my_data)  

    print(type(my_data))

    print("Data is")
    for i in my_data:
        print(i)

encoded = json.dumps(my_data)
data = json.loads(encoded)
print("JSON Data is")
for i in data:
    if isinstance(i, dict):
        for key, value in i.items():
            print(key, value)
    else:
        print(i)
```

But this only allows me to access the first level fields in json. I am writing in Python as you will see. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't really need to include 641 lines of JSON in your question. Also, why are you unserializing the JSON file into `my_data`, then serializing it back to JSON in `encoded`, and then unserializing it into `data`? That seems like a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: Where does the original CSV data come from? It looks like the value of `subscription` should probably be JSON, but it's not; it looks like somebody was printing a Python dictionary when they should have used `json.dumps`. This is going to make it unnecessarily painful to treat those values as a dictionary.

Comment: @larsks thanks, trying to teach myself how to do this. But thanks for drawing my attention to those unnecessary steps, perhaps it would be more helpful if you could suggest some good practice tips here? A better approach?

Comment: @larsks I didn't create the csv, it is part of a task.